# What API to use in Electron.js to know if other process is running, and on the main window?

Tags: electron, desktop-application

how to make my app know if other process are running on the background? What API to use? I'm on Linux and Windows.

Lest say I got tracker app, this app know if I'm using Chrome and it is on my main window. Are there any related Electron/Systems API that I cloud use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware Electron.js does not offer this. That said the various operating systems have APIs available you can use. Windows has the [GetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow) API available.

However, if you want to avoid that as it may require a lot of work to include it into your project, you may be able to leverage the [Active Window package here](https://github.com/octalmage/active-window). Please note that it is no longer maintained.

Comment: I also think that reading main window requires some native code too. Thanks for your direction.